# Cmake issue with building a small library

Tags: build, cmake

I am currently trying to deepen my understanding regarding CMake. I try to use http://libqglviewer.com/introduction.html]LibQGLViewer as a Third-Party library in a C++ Project of mine.

The CMakeLists.txt in the associated subdirectory looks like the following where the part, I have questions is the add_libary section and some header and source files were omitted for clarity

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.5.1 FATAL_ERROR)

set(target_name QGLViewerQt5)
project(${target_name})

message(STATUS "BUILDING QGLViewer-2.7.0 FROM SOURCE!")

set(BASE_DIR QGLViewer)
set(VRENDER_DIR VRender) 
set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC ON)

set(QGLheaders
    ${BASE_DIR}/camera.h
    ${BASE_DIR}/config.h
    ${BASE_DIR}/${VRENDER_DIR}/AxisAlignedBox.h
    ${BASE_DIR}/${VRENDER_DIR}/Exporter.h
)


set(QGLsources
    ${BASE_DIR}/camera.cpp
    ${BASE_DIR}/${VRENDER_DIR}/Exporter.cpp
)

add_library(${target_name} ${QGLsources} ${QGLheaders}) 
target_include_directories(${target_name} 
 PUBLIC .
)

target_link_libraries(${target_name}
  ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES}
  Qt5::Core
  Qt5::Widgets
  Qt5::Xml
  Qt5::OpenGL
)

set(CMAKE_AUTOMOC OFF)

install(TARGETS ${target_name} DESTINATION lib)
```

My Application runs and everything is fine.

However, I read that one should only include the source files with add_library and then use **target_include_directories** to consider the associated header files. So I changes the above part to

```
add_library(${target_name} SHARED ${QGLsources})
target_include_directories(${target_name} 
  PUBLIC 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/QGLViewer 
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/QGLViewer/VRender
  )
```

but now, I get an error trying to make my project

**fatal error: QGLViewer/qglviewer.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.**

can you please tell me

- What exactly does PUBLIC . do? I know what PUBLIC does but what does the point mean?
- Why does it not work as before?

thank you in advance

PS: The folder structure is as follows

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does call to `target_link_libraries` remain in the changed code?

Comment: yes it does and it is not affecting the outcome

Comment: @CarstenD I suggest you replace images of file tree with the [following representation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147467/is-there-a-good-way-to-represent-file-structure-in-a-question-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firts one, `target_include_directories()` has following syntax according [official docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) `target_include_directories(<target> [SYSTEM] [BEFORE]
 <INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items1...] [<INTERFACE|PUBLIC|PRIVATE> [items2...] ...])` as you see there few keywords might be used:

- `PRIVATE`: adds directories to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`
- `INTERFACE`: adds directories to `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` property of `<target>`
- `PUBLIC`: adds directories to `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` **and** `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` properties of `<target>`

What about those properties:

- `INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` - contains list of directories to search header files you used in project
- `INTERFACE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES` - contains list of directories to search header files too, **but** it has [transitivity](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements), that means you able to inherit your include directories to project linked through `target_link_libraries()`

Second one, your code doesn't work because you are using another include folders paths, your source file must be contain something like `#include <QGLViewer/qglviewer.h>` but since you do not include root folder anymore (`.` in your previous code), but linking QGLViewer directly - you must type `#include <qglviewer.h>`. Fix it for each `#include` you are using or add `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` to `target_include_directories` instead.

Comment: thank you a lot for your extensive answer : )    What is the difference between <QGLViewer> and "" Syntax?

Comment: @CarstenD, I suggest you to use search upon stackoverflow, it might be that your question is already has an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21594/4121301). And by the way, none of your questions has no accepted answer (even in case it has), if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. That an appropriate way to show gratitude.

Comment: thank you, I did check the answer now =)  Another question which I have is, how do I know if a certain library, e.g. OpenGL supports alias' like Qt does, i.e. Qt::Widgets and what is the use of those alias' anyway if I can just type     ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
and it does the same?

Comment: @CarstenD that not an alias, it is [namespace](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace). I'm not quite understand what you asking about and imho comments not the place to discuss off topic, it would be better to create another one question, or search for answers on the internet.